How to make AVAudioEngine with nodes persistent using NSKeyedArchiver?
Is it possible to use NSKeyedArchiver to save an AVAudioEngine, including all its nodes and connections, to a file and later restore it using NSKeyedUnarchiver?
If not, would Core Data or another API be more appropriate for achieving this?
I’ve searched Apple documentation and other resources online but found little discussion on this topic. Is this approach either so straightforward that it’s rarely questioned, or am I conceptualizing the task incorrectly?
Thanks in advance to anyone who can provide guidance!

Eventually figured this out through Apple's docs, going back to my CoreAudio dev days (2006 or so). The answer turned out be related to the old audio-unit property kAudioUnitProperty_ClassInfo . The modern method to be used with AVAudioEngine is fullstate located in the AUAudioUnit API (not the AVAudioUnit API as one might expect). It does exactly what I was looking for - provided an NSKeyedArchiver coddle form of all the settings needed for the audio unit.
The method documentation is here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/auaudiounit/1387500-fullstate?language=objc
